# SEO friendly JS framework

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, framework

I know Angular, prerender.io scared me because I have to use Angular Universal and has a big configuration process, and I'm not convinced by ng-toolkit, unless companies are using it in production successfully.

I'm going to stick with Angular for projects that don't require SEO, but otherwise, I'm looking for a framework that is:

- Simple
- Lightweight
- Easy to learn
- SEO friendly
- Free and open source

A plus if it resembles the way Angular works because I'm familiar with it.

Is there a framework like that or should I go back to using JS libraries like JQuery?